# GTKMM 4.10 - Obtain file filter selected in Gtk::FileDialog when presenting save() dialog to user

Tags: c++, gtk4, gtkmm4

I am converting C++ applications from GTKMM 4.8 to 4.10 and disabling deprecated classes and functions.  I used to use a `Gtk::FileChooserDialog` and am converting my applications to use the `Gtk::FileDialog` class instead.  In the deprecated `Gtk::FileChooser` class there was a member function `get_filter()` which returned the currently selected filter.  I used to use this in some of my applications to determine what format the user wishes to save the data in the application.  I have looked for an equivalent in the `Gtk::FileDialog` class but cannot find one.  Using the new class is there a way to determine what filter was selected ? I cannot guarantee that the user will append the correct extension to the filename entered and thus cannot use the filename as a means of determining filter selection.  The `get_default_filter()` member only returns the default file filter set when the dialog was created and run.  This is not what I want.

**Further investigations**

1. Reviewed signals for a `Gio::ListStore` to determine if there was one that fired when an item was selected.  The only one I could find was `signal_items_changed()` which only fires when items are added or removed from the list store.
2. Reviewed signals for a `Gtk::FileFilter` to determine if there was one that fired when an item was selected.  The only one I could find was `signal_changed` which only fires when the file filter's details are changed - not when it was selected.

**Further investigation re single selection models**

Created a `Gtk::SingleSelection` and then attached the list store that underlies the file filters to it.  As long as I set an initial selection then I could fetch the selected item from the selection object and then use this item number to fetch the file filter.  This is part way to a solution but how do I attach the selection model to the dialog or file filters so that when something changes I can obtain the file filter in question ?